# Finding $\lim (2^{n+1}-3)(2^n+1)^{-1}$ using the definition of a limit

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification, epsilon-delta

> Find $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}-3}{2^n+1}$ using the definition of a limit.

Attempt: For $\epsilon > 0$ take $N = \dfrac{\log{(1/\epsilon)}}{\log(2)}$. Then $n > N$ implies $\log(2^n) > \log(1/\epsilon)$ which implies $2^n > 1/\epsilon$ which gives $\dfrac{1}{2^n} < \epsilon$. But $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2^n} > \frac{1}{2^n+1} > \frac{-5}{2^{n}+1}$ so we have  $\displaystyle \frac{-5}{2^{n}+1} < \epsilon$ therefore

$\bigg|\dfrac{2^{n+1}-3-2(2^{n}+1)}{2^{n}+1}\bigg| < \epsilon \implies \bigg|\dfrac{2^{n+1}-3}{2^n+1}-2\bigg| < \epsilon$. Therefore we have $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2^{n+1}-3}{2^n+1} = 2.$

Is this correct? If not, how do you do it? And if it's how do ensure that $N = \dfrac{\log(1/\epsilon)}{\log(2)}$is an integer?

Comment: It is not very far from being right, but has a substantial error. You need to work with absolute value. It is enough to make $\frac{5}{2^n+1}\lt \epsilon$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks. When should I have started working with the absolute value? After I got out of the logs?

Comment: Logs come much later. Let $f(n)$ be your function. Then (basically your calculation)  $|f(n)-2|=\frac{5}{2^n+1}\lt \frac{5}{2^n}$. To make this $\lt \epsilon$, we want $2^n \gt \frac{5}{\epsilon}$. Now it is time for logging.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome. Please note again that the line after "Attempt:" has serious issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct. To ensure that $N$ is an integer, use the [ceiling function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions)
$$ N = \lceil \frac{-\log \epsilon}{\log 2} \rceil
$$

Comment: Thank you! Is it always the ceiling function or are there instances where we use the floor function instead?

Comment: @user129566 If you want to set an integral upper bound for something, you can use the floor function.